# Получение id выбранного элемента в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Есть диалог с RecycleView с векторными картинками, расположенными в GridLayoutManager. По нажатию на картинку, надо показать в родительской активити ту картинку, на которую нажали в диалоге. 
Я пытаюсь получить id в активити так:

```
chosenId = (int) avaRecycler.getAdapter().getItemId(position);
```

Но получаю -1.
Решил посмотреть откуда и почему. В адаптере:

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AvaViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.iv.setImageResource(resourceIds.get(position));
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder position: " + position + " | " + holder.toString());
}
```

Имею следующий результат:

```
onBindViewHolder position: 20 | ViewHolder{755353a position=20 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent}
```

Код адаптера

```
public class AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter.AvaViewHolder>{


private static final String TAG = "AvaChooseAdapter";
Context context;
private AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter.AvaViewHolder.MyClickListener myClickListener;

List<Integer> resourceIds = Arrays.asList(
        R.drawable.avatars_01, R.drawable.avatars_02, R.drawable.avatars_03,
        R.drawable.avatars_04, R.drawable.avatars_05, R.drawable.avatars_06,
               ....................
         R.drawable.avatars_66);

public AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter(Context context, AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter.AvaViewHolder.MyClickListener m) {
    this.context = context;
    //this.resourceIds = resourceIds;
    myClickListener = m;
}

public static class AvaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    protected MyClickListener myClickListener;
    protected ImageView iv;

    public AvaViewHolder(View itemView, MyClickListener myClickListener) {
        super(itemView);
        this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
        iv = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ava_item_imageview);
        iv.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (myClickListener != null) myClickListener.onAvaClickListener(getAdapterPosition());
    }

    public interface MyClickListener{
        void onAvaClickListener(int position);
    }
}

@Override
public AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter.AvaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    context = parent.getContext();
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ava_item, parent, false);
    v.setPadding(14, 14, 14, 14);
    return new AvaViewHolder(v, myClickListener);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AvaViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.iv.setImageResource(resourceIds.get(position));
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder position: " + position + " | " + holder.toString());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return resourceIds.size();
}
```

}

В активити:

```
final AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter avaChooseRecyclerAdapter = new AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter(PersonEditActivity.this, new AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter.AvaViewHolder.MyClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAvaClickListener(int position) {
                    Toast.makeText(view2.getContext(), "Выбрана ава " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //chosenId = avaRecycler.getChildAt(position).getId();
                    chosenId = (int) avaRecycler.getAdapter().getItemId(position);
                    Log.d("Жопа", String.valueOf(avaRecycler.getAdapter().getItemId(position)));
                }
            });
            avaRecycler.setAdapter(avaChooseRecyclerAdapter);
```

Comment: Я верно понимаю, что по нажатию на первую картинку должен увидеть в логах id=R.drawable.avatars_01 (тут id этой картинки, конечно)?

Comment: Вам нужно получить id картинки или что?

Comment: @РасулA-ев, я думаю да. В данный момент я считаю что надо узнать id нажатой картинки. Потом зная это, я смогу в активити показать картинку именно с тем id, который выбран в recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по тому, что пишут [здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition()), лучше вместо getAdapterPosition() использовать getLayoutPosition() при обработке OnClick в холдере:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (myClickListener != null) myClickListener.onAvaClickListener(getLayoutPosition());
}
```

getAdapterPosition() "может быть проблемой при использовании позиции ViewHolder для доступа к адаптеру", потому что RecyclerView как-то не сразу обновляет адаптер

upd: Похоже, что  Вам нужно переопределить `getItemId` адаптера - [здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemId(int)) говорят, что  у `RecyclerView.Adapter` этот метод по-умолчанию возвращает `NO_ID`, т.е. `-1`, а лучше сделать свой метод

```
public Integer getItemId(int position) {
    return resourceIds.get(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте код адаптера на этот:

```
public class AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter.AvaViewHolder> {


private static final String TAG = "AvaChooseAdapter";
Context context;
private AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter.AvaViewHolder.MyClickListener myClickListener;

public void setMyClickListener(AvaViewHolder.MyClickListener myClickListener) {
    this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
}

List<Integer> resourceIds = Arrays.asList(
        R.drawable.avatars_01, R.drawable.avatars_02, R.drawable.avatars_03,
        R.drawable.avatars_04, R.drawable.avatars_05, R.drawable.avatars_06,
           ....................
R.drawable.avatars_66);

public AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    //this.resourceIds = resourceIds;
}

public static class AvaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    protected MyClickListener myClickListener;
    protected ImageView iv;

    public AvaViewHolder(View itemView, MyClickListener myClickListener) {
        super(itemView);
        this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
        iv = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ava_item_imageview);
        iv.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (myClickListener != null) myClickListener.onAvaClickListener(getAdapterPosition());
    }

    interface MyClickListener {
        void onAvaClickListener(int position);
    }

}

@Override
public AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter.AvaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    context = parent.getContext();
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ava_item, parent, false);
    v.setPadding(14, 14, 14, 14);
    return new AvaViewHolder(v, myClickListener);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AvaViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.iv.setImageResource(resourceIds.get(position));
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder position: " + position + " | " + holder.toString());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return resourceIds.size();
}
```

}

А в активити напишите следующим образом:

```
final AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter recAdapter = new AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter(this);

    recAdapter.setMyClickListener(new AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter.AvaViewHolder.MyClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAvaClickListener(int position) {
            // Здесь id выбранного изображения. Можете использовать как хотите
            int chosenId = recAdapter.resourceIds.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(view2.getContext(), "Выбрана ава " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Жопа", String.valueOf(chosenId));
            recAdapter.resourceIds.get(position);
        }
    });
```